# cant start browser from my app

Tags: android, url, browser

When I use this piece of code:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I get these error messages:

```
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = dev.socialnet.server.Server)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = dev.socialnet.server.Server)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2026)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1897)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:1078)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.content.Intent.getBundleExtra(Intent.java:3843)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity.handleWebSearchIntent(BrowserActivity.java:1463)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity.onCreate(BrowserActivity.java:488)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     ... 11 more
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.socialnet.server.Server
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2564)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1823)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:811)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2039)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:916)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2020)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     ... 20 more
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev.socialnet.server.Server
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     ... 30 more
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.socialnet.server.Server in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/twframework.jar:/system/framework/sec_feature.jar:/system/framework/sechardware.jar:/system/app/Browser.apk]
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-26 18:14:35.305: E/AndroidRuntime(9427):     ... 30 more
```

Comment: have you tried some other url, the crash seems to be in browserActivity rather than yours. Are you using any class dev.socialnet.server.Server?

Comment: I've tried several urls. Yes dev.socalnet.server.Server is in the project. That's being used for getting things out of the database via json objects. Btw it's not my own project but from someone who is a lot more advanced at android than me so I might not see some things.

Comment: Is the Server.java inside library? are you starting browser in ui thread and from a Activity?

Comment: no Server.java is a self written class. I'm starting the browser intent from an Activity

Comment: oke found it!
I seem to use superStartActivity() wich is a method written in the parent and calls super.startActivity() there

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at this.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(url));
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Or..

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/");   
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

Comment: And if it still does not work, could you explain where you are using dev.socialnet.server.Server class ?

Comment: Tried the first and got the same error. The second thing is the same as I have in my code.

Comment: íts not easy to type that out but it's used in this line:
    Method method = serverInstance.getClass().getMethod(serverMethod, methodArgTypes);

Answer (score 0):

I feel your activity missing in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity
            android:name="dev.socialnet.server.Server"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
```

Comment: Could you please add your AndroidManifest.xml and whole activity class, so that i can figure out where actual problem is.

Comment: oke found it!
I seem to use superStartActivity() wich is a method written in the parent and calls super.startActivity() there

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hack around the problem by removing the extra containing the classname from the intent.
In my case it was "clazz=com.example.ExampleActivity". To remove the extra I did this in the startActivity method from the my activity.

```
@Override
public void startActivity( final Intent intent, final Bundle options )
{
    intent.removeExtra( "clazz" );
    super.startActivity( intent, options );
}
```

FYI: I encountered the problem when opening links (mailto and http) from a webview by overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading of the WebViewClient.

Hope this helps someone (took me ~2.5h to find a solution).

Comment: I just realized that I added the clazz extra myself... so I renamed it to something else and removed the removeExtra call. Again, the same problem. So what I've learned so far from this is: Never serialized classes around with intents (espacially to other built-in apps).